# Groups of prime squared order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

[image]

I have done part $a$ and $b$, stuck on $c$. I don't know what to do here. I know that since $G$ has order $p^2$, any  element must have order $1, p$ or $p^2$ so any generator must have one of those orders, but I don't know how to reason any further..

Answer (score 6):

So if you have no elements of order $p^2$, then all your elements have order $p$. Hence every group you have is cyclic of order $p$. Since they meet at the identity, there is a total of $x(p-1)+1=p^2$ elements. $x$ is what?

Comment: interesting.. but I don't understand why we don't have any elements of order $p^2$.

Comment: If you did, your group would be cyclic.

Comment: so any generator always has the same order as the group?

Comment: If you have an element whose order is the size of the group, then that element generates your group and thus it would be a cyclic group.

Comment: thank you for that answer. is the converse true then, that if i have a cyclic group with order d, there must be an element of order d?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: alright thanks again. i'm still confused as to how to determine the nature of the subgroups of G though. I know at least one element in my cylic group G has order $p^2$, but I don't know how many..

Comment: @Ryan, take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_cyclic_groups). It gives you a characterisation of cyclic groups.

Answer (score 2):

The following is, imo, a rather nice though perhaps not so used way to answer (c): first, if $\;G\;$ is cyclic there's nothing to prove as a finite cyclic group has one unique subgroup of each and every divisor of its order, so let us assume $\;G\;$ is not cyclic.

(1) Prove $\;G\cong C_p\times C_p\;$ , with $\;C_p=$ the cyclic group of order $\;p\;$ .

(2) Under the "scalar product" $\;k\cdot g:=g^k\;,\;\;g\in G\;,\;\;k\in \Bbb F_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ , prove that $\;G\;$ is a vector space over the field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ (note that *as groups*, $\Bbb F_p\cong C_p\;$ , of course)

(3) Now show that "vector subspace" and "subgroup" are exactly the same in this case.

(4) Finally, count how many $\;1-$dimensional subspaces $\;G\;$ has...

Answer (score 1):

Here we know the group itself has order $p^{2}$, so if it is cyclic then you have a unique order $p$ subgroup. Otherwise pick up another element $b$ not in the $p$-group $A$ we already chosen, and we may argue that $|b|=p$ . Since you already proved that the intersection of $\langle b \rangle\cap A=e$, you can show $G=A\times \langle b\rangle$. So the group must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Counting multiplicity of subgroups generated by pair $(x,y)$ and you find it is $p+1$.

Comment: I don't believe I'm allowed to use that theorem, that a cyclic group has a unique order subgroup for all the divisors. It's explicitly stated on this assignment that I can only use certain theorems and that one is not listed.

Comment: No, you don't have to use it. Prove for $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z}$ it has a unique subgroup of order $p$ yourself. This is not difficult.

Comment: Maybe for you it's not...

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry. Assume $x=a\pmod{p}$ where $a\not=0$. Then $px=pa\pmod{p^{2}}$. Since $pa$ has order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z}$, you may conclude $x$ has order $p^{2}$. So the only subgroup of order $p$ is the one generated by $1,p,2p\cdots p^{2}$.

Comment: no worries, and thank you. you guys are just a lot smarter than me.